# Clamp a PHP variable to a 0-to-4 range

Tags: php

I have a legacy code written as below:

```
if($value < 0) {
    $value = 0;
}
if($value > 4) {
    $value = 4;
}
```

Is there an easier and more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `min(max($value, 0), 4)`? But it could be a discussed, whether this is really easier.

Comment: @insertusernamehere this actually looks better but I'm not sure if this is faster. Since I didn't ask for it to be faster, it's good enough :)

Comment: Maybe it's not, but this might be micro optimization. This isn't an accurate test, but take a look at [this](https://3v4l.org/5bA4N/perf#output) and [this](https://3v4l.org/Ku4BX/perf#output) performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting the "best" method in this case is likely going to come down to personal preference.

If you wish to use a condition-less one-liner, then insertusernamehere's offering is brief/elegant.  However, it is not instantly comprehensible for the next developer.

```
min(max($value, 0), 4)
```

---

If you want a one-liner with conditions (or without functions), then this is what Billal was mentioning:

```
$value < 0 ? 0 : ($value > 4 ? 4 : $value)
```

However, the php manual says:

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions.

---

I personally find switch statements to be too clunky/verbose with the `break`ing.  While it is nice that it only evaluates `$value` once, that is of very little benefit in your tiny use case.

---

Finally, I recommend simply changing your second `if` statement to `elseif` so that the second statement is ignored when the first is true.  This method will be fast, clean, and instantly comprehensible.

```
if ($value < 0) {
    $value = 0;
} elseif ($value > 4) {
    $value = 4;
}
```

...if `> 4` occurs more often than `< 0`, then reverse the order of the conditionals.

Here is a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b0a75312e3eaa45092219109e5f1f91541975c7) snippet:

```
$input = [-1, 0, 2, 4, 7];
foreach ($input as $value) {
    echo min(max($value, 0), 4) , "\n";
    echo $value < 0 ? 0 : ($value > 4 ? 4 : $value) , "\n";
    if ($value < 0) {
        $value = 0;
    } elseif ($value > 4) {
        $value = 4;
    }
    echo $value , "\n---\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Alternatives:**

1. [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): This is a bad option because you will need to nest ternary operators, and you will end up by a code which is not straightforward and easy to read.
2. Switch statement: You will end up by an easy to read code, but you will have to code few more lines than what you actually have.

**Conclusion:**

IMHO, you can not do better than what you did, and maybe your case falls into [**good enough**](https://www.intellectiongroup.com/recent-blog/good-enough-software) software principle.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with a lot of the solutions in this thread is that they don't mention the problem space in the code, variable names help signal intent

```
$upper_clamp = $value > 4;
$upper_clamp && $value = 4;

$lower_clamp = $value < 0;
$lower_clamp && $value = 0;
```

If you want the micro optimisation of not checking the second case you could do something like this:

```
switch (TRUE) {
  case $upper_clamp = $value > 4: 
    return 4;
  case $lower_clamp = $value < 0:
    return 0;
  default: 
    return $value;
 }
```

Just because if statements and switch statements etc allow you to not use a variable name doesn't mean you should not use one, they can help understanding of code.

Writing code with missing variable names is like writing a novel where you describe everything that is happening but skip writing any describing words